# How to flush a buffer in a ADS stored procedure?

Tags: stored-functions, advantage-database-server

I've inherited a stored procedure that works perfectly when we are running single user, but when more than one user is running the procedure all hell breaks lose. I know this is poor structure but like I said, I inherited it and have to live with it.

Is there any way to flush the buffer after set line? I just want to make sure the number generated is always unique.

```
  begin transaction;
  try
    update s  
    set s.NEXT_YMMPC = s.NEXT_YMMPC + 1
    from system s;

    @YMMPC_Key = (select top 1 cast(s.NEXT_YMMPC as sql_char(10)) from system s);
    @YMMPC_Key = right('0000000'+trim(@YMMPC_Key),10);

    insert into YMMProductCatalog (Year,MakeCode,ModelCode,ProductCode,CatalogCode,YMMPC_Key) values (@Year,@MakeCode,@ModelCode,@ProductCode,@CatalogCode,@YMMPC_Key);

    commit work;

    insert into __output select @YMMPC_Key from system.iota;

  catch all
    rollback work;
    raise;  

  end;
```

TIA - Jay

Comment: You need to explain what you meant by "all hell breaks lose". Did the procedure raise exception or was the result incorrect? From what I can tell, the procedure should run just fine with multiple users.There is no buffer to flush. The procedure performs the update to the "system" table and insert into the YMMProductCatalog table as an atomic operation using transaction.

Comment: no exceptions are raised but what is support to be unique number gets duplicated creating bad references.  I agree it looks like it should work.

Comment: it's part of parent/child relationship between 2 tables.  children records are begin assigned to wrong parents because the unique key is duplicated.

Comment: Are you using Advantage DB server or Advantage Local Server?